# Can Java Protocol Buffers ever return null on the list getter of a repeated field?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Say you have a repeated field.

```
message Foo {
  optional int32 val = 1;
}

message Bar {
  repeated Foo foo = 1;
}
```

This will generate the method

```
List<Foo> getFooList()
```

Is there any circumstance where `getFooList` will return `null`? Or will it always return a `List`, even if it's empty?

Comment: It always returns non-null value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no case where it returns `null`.  In fact, none of the field accessors on Java protobuf generated classes ever return `null`; they always return the default value if the field is not present.  Similarly, the setters do not allow you to set `null`.

Comment: "no case where it returns null" - Is there a reference for this?

Comment: @hongsy I wrote the original Proto2 Java implementation. But I haven't worked on protobuf in a very long time so everything could be different now?

Comment: or perhaps there might be some documentation that could point me to Java protobufs and `null`?

Comment: @hongsy Sorry but I haven't looked at the protobuf-java docs in ten years. I don't remember anything about them and they've probably all changed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that no Java protocol buffer methods accept or return nulls unless otherwise specified.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated

Comment: but what if the field is not set in the parsed object?

Comment: If you try to set a null value to a proto-buffer builder, it will throw an exception. If you get a value from a non-set field of a proto-buffer object, it will return a zero value just like a non-initialized Java member field.

Answer (score 1):

> The default value for repeated fields is empty (generally an empty list in the appropriate language).

Source: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default